# What is meant by output Leakage Current?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, power-electronics

Is output Leakage Current= Output Current - Input Current?

I encountered the term in a datasheet of the [L9938 driver](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000235.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output leakage current is universally understood to mean the current which flows through a device's output terminals - with voltage across them - when its input commands the output to be in an OFF (open circuit) condition.

A simple example is a form "A" (single-pole single-throw normally open) relay with no coil excitation.